# Magento PWA: How to setup venia storefront theme in localhost?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to setup venia storefront theme with magento 2.3.3 instance. When i try to install the venia sample data according to magento pwa docs. It's not installing. Also i tried to run and build the pwa studio folder concent. But it gives me following error.
[image]

[image]

My os is windows 10. What is the best way to install venia storefront in windows?

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to install Venia sample data**

[From Magento PWA Documentation](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/install-sample-data/)

**Step 1. Copy or create the deploy script**

If you have cloned the PWA Studio repository into the same machine as your Magento instance, copy over the following PWA Studio file into the root directory of your Magento instance:

```
packages/venia-concept/deployVeniaSampleData.sh
```

If you do not have access to the PWA Studio repository, copy the following content into a file in the root directory of your Magento instance:

```
Show content for deployVeniaSampleData.sh
```

**Step 2. Execute the deploy script**

Execute the script in the root directory of your Magento instance to add the Venia sample data modules to Magento:

```
bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh
```

**Step 3. Install the sample data modules**

Run the following command in the Magento root directory to install the Venia data from the modules:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Step 4. Reindex the new data**

Run the following command in the Magento root directory to reindex the data from the modules:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**Step 5. Verify installation**

Log into the Admin section or visit the store of your Magento instance to verify the sample data installation.